# Line graph with week of year for different years

Tags: graph, stata

I'm trying to create a single graph with same week period on the x-axis and let's say sales on the y-axis, but different years overlaid with different colors.

I have a panel dataset containing data from 2019 jan 01 to 2020 dec 31.

So, I want the x-axis to start at week 1 and end with week 52 (total 52 weeks) without year information.

How would I go about doing it with Stata?

So far I've tried

```
tw line y date if date < tw(2020w1)  || line y date if date >= tw(2020w1)
```

but this code would yield an x-axis from week 1 of 2019 to week 52 of 2020 (total of 104 weeks), and does not overlay different years on the same week as axis.

Comment: You can make a variable that takes a value between 1 and 52 (for weeks) regardless of years, and then replace the variable date in your `twoway` by this week variable. If you need further assistance, please show us a reproducible example with the data format of your date variable.

Comment: @krasnapolsky thanks! I'll try generating dummies as you mentioned, and if that fails I'll try to replicate the data with dataex

Comment: Not dummies, create one variable called `week` with the integers 1,2,3 ... 50,51,52. Then you can use `tw line sale week if year == 2019 || line sale week if year == 2020`. I recommend creating a variable `year` with the year as the code `if year == 2020` is easier to read than `if date >= tw(2020w1)`.

Comment: @TheIceBear Using the following code I was able to create just integers 1,2,3... 52 egen week = seq(), to(52)  and I followed your instructions of tw line command and finally problem solved! Thx for the advice , all!

Answer (score 0):

The following created integers from 1 to 52:

```
 egen week = seq(), to(52)
```

then

```
 tw line sale week if year == 2019 || line sale week if year == 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Stata weeks begin on 1 January, 8 January, 15 January, ... always,  with week 52 always 8 or 9 days and never a week 53. If that maps 1:1 on to what you have, then well and good.

Otherwise, see the references yielded by  `search week, sj` for other advice.

With the proviso just above `week(dofw())` pulls the week of the year out of a weekly date, so yields 1 to 52 if the argument is a Stata weekly date. So, you shouldn't need to invent your own week number variable. The information is necessarily embedded in the Stata weekly dates you appear to have.